# Javascript: draw animated line by giving the points

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I got some code to draw the animation one by one. But the first line is visible,  before the animation starts. Please let me know what to change in the below code that draws the line.

I have not provided enough detail about what I want this to do, and I will add some more later.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  function Character1(canvas, progress, duration, delay) {
    console.log("c1 " + progress);

    delay = delay || 1;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    debugger;

    if (progress < duration) {

      canvas.strokeStyle = "black";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(1, 13);
      ctx.lineTo(1 * ((progress + 1) / duration), 30);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath()

      setTimeout(function() {
        Character1(canvas, progress + 1, duration, delay);
      }, delay);

    } else {
      debugger;
      $(document.body).trigger("Character1Completed");
    }
  }



  // Start Drawing
  Character1(canvas, 0, 30, 33);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: posting a fiddle might help others to understand the problem quickly

Comment: like the following fiddle i am trying to do                                                       http://jsfiddle.net/UtmTh/          If you try running the above code it works. but the line is visible before the animation starts.

Comment: above fiddle works fine, line is not visible before the animation starts.

Comment: That fiddle works fine. But in the same way i am trying to do. In my code the line is visible.